# Not logging off in Xfce when closing the lid

Tags: configuration, xfce, pop-os

After some read and search through the net, I am still having the following problem.
I am using Pop!_OS on a Lenovo X230. After some time with GNOME DE, I have decided to see how Xfce DE looks like. While still in progress to know it better, I have encountered the following issue. In GNOME when I close the lid, and then bring the lid back again I am required to put the login password, but it is not the case in Xfce. How do I change that? The power manager has no such option (after really checking different combinations of things). Also I tried to edit `logind.conf` file:

```
  GNU nano 5.2                                         /var/tmp/logindXXgwJbx5.conf                                                    
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
HandleSuspendKey=lock
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=lock
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
```

In which I uncommented and edited `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` to `HandleLidSwitch=lock`. This (after rebooting) didn't cause any visible effect.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: @A.B: There are three options under 'When laptop lid is closed', namely 'switch off display', 'suspend', 'lock screen'; those three appear also in plugged version. Non of these when chosen make the login screen after the lid is opened agian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following reddit thread one can find a solution that worked for me. Basically, there you can find in detail instruction to switch from Light-locker to XScreenSaver.
User ID: u/EMH_Mark_I

https://www.reddit.com/r/xubuntu/comments/9tlnnu/how_to_setup_xscreensaver_to_lock_on_suspend_for/